# pyppeteer.errors.BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly

Tags: pyppeteer

Today, I learn the lib called pyppeteer,When I run my code

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch


async def main():
    browser = await launch(options={'devtools': True, 'headless': False})
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://example.com')
    await page.screenshot({'path': 'baidu.png'})
    await browser.close()


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

I got:

```
pyppeteer.errors.BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly:
```

Answer (score 31):

This is because `pyppeteer` will **not** install the required dependencies by `chromium`. So you should install them yourself.

Execute `ldd ~/.local/share/pyppeteer/local-chromium/588429/chrome-linux/chrome | grep 'not found'` to fetch the lost dependencies:

Example output:

```
libXcursor.so.1 => not found
libnss3.so => not found
libnssutil3.so => not found
libsmime3.so => not found
libcups.so.2 => not found
libXss.so.1 => not found
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => not found
libpango-1.0.so.0 => not found
libcairo.so.2 => not found
libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgtk-3.so.0 => not found
libgdk-3.so.0 => not found
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => not found
```

You can install them one by one, or install `google-chrome` to install its dependencies.

For ubuntu/debian:

```sh
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

Execute `ldd ~/.local/share/pyppeteer/local-chromium/588429/chrome-linux/chrome | grep 'not found'` again, there may be some dependencies missed:

```
libXss.so.1 => not found
```

Then execute `apt install libxss1` to install the missed `libXss.so.1`

**Extra**

If you want do screenshot, maybe you need some CJK fonts:

`sudo apt install fonts-wqy-zenhei`

Comment: That's the only thing that helped me. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't realize I already upvoted this before.

Answer (score 16):

For me, I was running in docker and it ended up being that chromium didn't install the needed libs properly: https://techoverflow.net/2018/06/05/how-to-fix-puppetteer-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libx11-xcb-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/

Answer (score 14):

I got same and when I tried to start chromium from terminal I get notice that it needs to be run with no sandbox arg, so just add it and you code will work:

```
browser=await launch(options={'args': ['--no-sandbox']})
```

Comment: Why is the sandbox relevant?

Comment: Does not fix it for me.

Comment: Holy crap!  This worked for me!  I tried a lot of things in this thread, but this one finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think we need to install the drivers of chrome .

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

Thats the issue i am geeting

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem running `pyppeteer` via `cron`.

I had previously added

```bash
export http_proxy=...
```

to my `cron` `env` since without that, `pyppeteer` would time out getting documents. With `http_proxy`, `pyppeteer` would close unexpectedly.

Comparing my `env` (where it worked) with that of a `cron` job, I found what the `cron` job was missing was

```bash
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Exactly this in my case. The only difference is I had proxy connection set up from inside the script as `os.environ['http_proxy']`

Answer (score 1):

To know exactly the reason you can run these two commands on your python3 cmd:

```
from pyppeteer.launcher import Launcher
' '.join(Launcher().cmd)
```

and view the results.

But mostly the reason is that you are running your python script as root. You either need to add the "--no-sandbox" configuration or just run the script as another user (any user rather than root)

Comment: Your code shows all the options which is nice but how does it solve the problem?

Comment: I used `sudo` as `root` to run my code under a different user, but that still triggered the error. Running as a normal user solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me, as the repos kept failing to locate the packages needed.

However, installing the all of the necessary dependencies can be achieved with the following.

`sudo apt install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget`

for reference: https://techoverflow.net/2020/09/29/how-to-fix-pyppeteer-pyppeteer-errors-browsererror-browser-closed-unexpectedly/