# Pyppeteer Browser closed unexpectedly in heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, pip, pyppeteer

I recently deployed an app in heroku . It uses python pyppeteer package. I didnt had any issues while testing on repl.it. But unfortunately in heroku the browser keeps crashing.

I used requirement.txt for installing pyppeteer package.
I also tried using apt heroku buildpack for installing the requirements needed for pupeteer to work as per [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix)

My program :

```
async def mainer(link, path, is_image):
    browser = await launch(args=['--no-sandbox'])
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(link)
    if is_image:
        await page.screenshot({'path': f'{path}', 'fullPage': True, 'type': 'png'})
    else:
        await page.pdf({'path': f'{path}'})
    await browser.close()
```

here is the full traceback error from heroku :

```
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115643+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115644+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/plugins/downloader.py", line 61, in cb_
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115645+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await mainer(url,file,mode)
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115645+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/plugins/downloader.py", line 13, in mainer
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115646+00:00 app[worker.1]:     browser = await launch(args=['--no-sandbox'])
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115646+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 305, in launch
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115647+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115648+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 166, in launch
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115648+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.browserWSEndpoint = get_ws_endpoint(self.url)
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115648+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 225, in get_ws_endpoint
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115649+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise BrowserError('Browser closed unexpectedly:\n')
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115649+00:00 app[worker.1]: pyppeteer.errors.BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly:
2020-05-14T19:39:50.115650+00:00 app[worker.1]:
```

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780476/pyppeteer-browser-closed-unexpectedly-in-aws-lambda/63076355#63076355

Comment: @David Hey thanks for the comment , but i already fixed it by using Chromedriver from Heroku buildpack in  Executablepath  instead of the one bundled with Pyppeteer  :)

Comment: how ? what is the executable path ?

Comment: @AahnikDaw checkout the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we care using the [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome) provided by Heroku, there will be an environmental variable called [`GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM`](https://github.com/alenpaul2001/Web-Screenshot-Bot/blob/75741c8e30b6ee2a7b7697f09d2d94e8b51f899e/plugins/tool_bundle.py#L23). We can use this variable as an argument to [`pyppeteer.launch()`](https://github.com/alenpaul2001/Web-Screenshot-Bot/blob/75741c8e30b6ee2a7b7697f09d2d94e8b51f899e/plugins/tool_bundle.py#L211) or `webdriver.Chrome()`.

Comment: Have the same problem than you over heroku and pyppeteer!
My code it's exactly as yours. I'm using the buildpack: https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack.git

How did you solve it? Can you help me? I am a newbie in heroku

Comment: @dina which language are you using?

Comment: I'm using python

Comment: Yes please!!!, I'm using telegram too. Could you give me your alias? thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Heroku Deployment I had this issue

```
pyppeteer.errors.BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly:
```

Following [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku), I just added '--no-sandbox' mode when launching Puppeteer and 'headless' set to True.

```
from pyppeteer import launch
    BROWSER = await launch({'headless': True, 'args': ['--no-sandbox']})
```

I added 2 buildpacks in my dyno settings:

- [puppeteer-heroku-buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack)
- [heroku-buildpack-google-chrome](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome)

[image]

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Using Django, when i call requests_html HTMLSession at start of my application i needed to add [puppeteer-heroku-buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack) , [heroku-buildpack-google-chrome](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome) as first buildspacks and heroku/python as last. In code had to add something like this: *session = HTMLSession(browser_args=["--no-sandbox"])*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31248267)